# $L_{k}^{1}([0,1])$ is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $L_{k}^{1}([0,1])$ be the space of all $f\in C^{k-1}([0,1])$ such that $f^{(k-1)}$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ (and hence $f^{(k)}$ exists a.e. and is in $L^{1}([0,1])$). Show that $||f||=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}|f^{(j)}(x)|\;dx$ is a norm on $L_{k}^{1}([0,1])$ that makes it into a Banach space.

I can show that the given expression is a norm but I'm having some trouble showing that the space is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completeness of this space can be shown by the following argument: Take a cauchy-sequence $f_n$ and consider the sequence of functions $(f_n, f^{(1)}_n, \ldots, f^{(k)}_n) \in L^1([0,1])^{k+1}$. What can be said about this sequence? What follows for the original sequence $f_n$?

Let my know if this helps or if you need additional hints.

Comment: If $f_n$ is a Cauchy in $L_k^1$, then $(f_n, f^{(1)}_n, \ldots, f^{(k)}_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^1([0,1])^{k+1}$. By completeness of $L^1$, it converges towards $(u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_k)$. Now, it remains to show, that the $u_l$ are the derivatives of the $u_0$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing that those are derivatives of $u_{0}$. It seems that the key is to show that if $(f_{n})$ converges in $L^{1}([0,1])$ to $f$, then $(f_{n}')$ converges in $L^{1}([0,1])$ to $f'$ but I can't work that out.

Comment: But you have the additional information, that $f_n'$ already converges in $L^1$. You may also 'reconstruct' $f$ by integrating over $f'$.